# Можно ли писать на Java AR/VR?

Tags: java, поиск-библиотек, ar, vr

В следующем году планирую попытать удачу на Wordskills Russia. В IT направлении. И из интересного там только  AR/VR приложение. Кайфую только от Java, какие библиотеки и технологии нужны для этого?